# Why does "file foo.css" and "file bar.css" have different outputs?

Tags: files

For example, executing `file styles.css` outputs:

```
styles.css: asssembler source text
```

whereas `file bar.css` outputs:

```
bar.css: ASCII text
```

Even better, is there a way to convert my file `styles.css` to ASCII text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results from `file` are not perfect; the command looks for predictable patterns to determine file types. The `file` command is guessing. Apparently it has identified some keywords for assembly. The character encoding is almost certainly ASCII or UTF-8 already. But it can be checked:

```
file -bi $filename
```

Both `recode` and `iconv` can change the encoding of a file.